# ЯП с синтаксисом как у C#, поддержкой ООП и без автоматического сборщика мусора

Tags: c#, ооп, производительность, сборщик-мусора

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие существуют языки программирования (кроме с++) с синтаксисом похожим на C#, чтобы поддерживал ООП и не использовал автоматический сборщик мусора.

Comment: @unior00p: а зачем вам, если не секрет? У вас предубеждение против сборки мусора, или ваш интерес чисто академический?

Comment: @VladD, тормаза и локи, тухлая и изначально тупиковая концепция, не?

Comment: @o2n3e: Насчёт изначально тупиковой концепции хотелось бы пруфов с фактами и мнением серьёзных специалистов. Боюсь, мои тесты не подкрепляют вашу точку зрения.

Comment: @VladD просто я привык к cи подобному синтаксису. При рендеринге графики и её обработке ручное управление памятью все же намного лучше чем автоматическое.

Comment: @unior00p: ах, ручной рендеринг графики! Тогда понятно. Может, тогда ну её, объектную ориентацию? Написать рендеринг на чистом С, а бизнес-логику на каком-нибудь подходящем для этого языке, да хоть на том же С#?

Comment: @o2n3e: вы так и не привели мнение специалистов. Попробуйте простые тесты на скорость выделения памяти на C++ и C#, может быть, вы будете удивлены результатом. А пока я не вижу в ваших аргументах ни грамма доказательности, простите. Дальнейшую дискуссию до предоставления вами подкреплённого фактажом мнения специалистов считаю неконструктивной.

Comment: Вот ты представь, что ты идёшь по дороге и кидаешь бумажки напол, а за тобой идёт мусорщик. Он должен подбирать каждую бумажку и смотреть - есть ли на ней точка, если есть - он её поднимает. 


Вы с мусорщиком не можете идти вместе, ибо бумажки у тебя кончатся и он тебя никогда не догонит - поэтому каждый раз, когда мусорщик начинает идти к тебе - ты останавливаешься. Мусорщик проходит путь - проверяет все бумажки, брошеные тобой, собирает с точкой и даёт их тебе. Потом возвращается на начало своего пути.


Или: Ты идёшь и перед тем как бросить бумажку смотришь - если с точкой не бросаешь.

Comment: >> Написать рендеринг на чистом С

В чем крутость писать на "чистом С"?

Comment: В том чтобы не смешивать высокий и низкий уровень?

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev если вы считаете С низкоуровневым языком, то вы жутко ошибаетесь.

Comment: > если вы считаете С низкоуровневым языком, то вы жутко ошибаетесь.

м? Его используют для более деликатных и низкоуровневых вещей.

Расскажите мне про мои ошибки.

Comment: На С вы не взаимодействуете напрямую с аппаратурой процессора, С предоставляет некоторый уровень абстракции. Открываете википедию и читаете "Си часто называют языком среднего уровня или даже низкого уровня, учитывая то, как близко он работает к реальным устройствам. Однако, в строгой классификации, он является языком высокого уровня.". Так можно фортран, алгол, паскаль, бэйсик на начальном этапе его развития и т.п.. То что язык процедурный лишь косвенно связано с его высокоуровневостью. Инструкцию высокоуровневого языка можно заменить набором инструкций языка низкоуровневого.

Comment: @o2n3e. в .Net есть такое понятие, как поколение объектов. Если мусор переживает 1 сборку мусора, то поколение повышается, чем старше поколение, тем реже оно проверяется. => в твоем примере мусорщик будет часто проверять свежие бумажки и лишь после этого(если нужное кол-во памяти по прежнему нет) возвращаться назад и анализирвовать их.

Comment: @o2n3e, и ручная работа с памятью не в 100% будет быстрее сборщика мусора. 1) Не каждый имеет большой скилл в С++=>какие-нибудь стажировщики или кто только стал программистом будут писать медленный код. 2)Головная боль с утечками памяти 3)С++ , вроде, пошел по пути сборщика мусора. Туда, вроде, недавно завезли умные указатели, которые легче в работе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Vala](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala)

[Vala For CSharp Programmers](https://live.gnome.org/Vala/ValaForCSharpProgrammers)

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Comment: @Merlin, а разве в Vala нет сборки мусора?

Comment: Есть, но [можно управлять памятью вручную][1] 


  [1]: http://eax.me/vala/

Answer (score 2):

[D Language](http://dlang.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C.